# Drupal and Session Limit

Tags: sessions, distributions

I am using Drupal 6 with the Open Atrium distribution. **Is there a problem if the same user connects from more than 100 different computers at the same time?** At the moment I am unable to do a test but I would like to know if I can encounter any problem. So far I did try with 10 PCs and no problem whatsoever. Also is there a limit that I have to remove or by default there is no limit? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hardcoded limit, but sessions by default are kept in database, so user<->session queries will get slow like a hell pretty soon. Move sessions to memcache or apc if possible, and consider giving each of those 100 guys his own account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I cannot give them a personal account for reasons that I can't explain here (it's not a technical reason anyway). Perhaps I need to ask another question but do you know where I can find information regarding moving a table to APC? Thx.

Comment: Google. Really. It's so easy to google for drupal's sessions in apc that I refuse to do it for you.

Comment: Forgive my question but what is the difference between having 100 different accounts and having a single account? In the end if all of these users are connected at the same moment what will change in the session table?